# const member returned as non-const

Tags: c++, reference, constants

In the following simple example

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class Dumb {
    public:
        typedef const std::vector<double> result_type;
    private:
        result_type mat_;
    public:
        Dumb(const result_type& mat) : mat_(mat) {}
        const result_type& get() const {
          std::cout << "const return" << std::endl;
          return mat_;
        }
        result_type& get() {
          std::cout << "non-const return" << std::endl;
          return mat_;
        }
};


int main(int,char*[]){
    const std::vector<double> B(5,1.0);
    const Dumb d(B);
    d.get();
    std::cout << "d " << typeid(d).name() << " "
          << std::is_const<decltype(d)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d.get() " << typeid(d.get()).name() << " "
          << std::is_const<decltype(d.get())>::value << std::endl;
}
```

which yields the output

```
const return
d N12_GLOBAL__N_14DumbE 1
d.get() NSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEEE 0
```

e.g.

```
const return
double (anonymous namespace)::Dumb 1
d.get() std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > 0
```

Why does `d.get()` return a non-const vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It *is* `const`!**

The mistake here is in the way you're testing. `is_const` is simply telling you that the reference type is not `const`, which is always true.

It's better to test this stuff directly, e.g. [by trying to mutate the result of `d.get()`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c9bcd5b1f2c5c74):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Dumb
{
    public:
        typedef const std::vector<double> result_type;
    private:
        result_type mat_;
    public:
        Dumb(const result_type& mat) : mat_(mat) {}
        const result_type& get() const { return mat_; }
        result_type& get() { return mat_; }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    const std::vector<double> B(5,1.0);
    const Dumb d(B);
    d.get().push_back(6);
}

// error:
//  no matching function for call to 'std::vector<double>::push_back(int) const'
```

From this, it's clear that `d.get()` *is* `const std::vector<double>&`.

Answer (score 3):

`decltype(d.get())` is a reference type; reference types can't be const-qualified (although their underlying object type can be), and so `is_const` will be false.

If you test the underlying object type, `std::remove_reference<decltype(d.get())>::type`, then `is_const` should be true.